# Laravel Faker lowercase

Tags: laravel, faker

This sounds very trivial but I can't seem to figure it out...

I normally have my db columns like so;

```
Table Name: City
**id** - 1
**name** - Cityx
**value** - cityx
```

as you can see **value** is exactly like **name** but in lowercase.
Now I'm trying to use `$faker` for php and wondering how I would do this

```
$factory->define(App\City::class, function ($faker) {
    return [
        'city' => $faker->city,
        'value' => , // make this lower case of $faker->city
    ];
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$factory->define(App\City::class, function ($faker) {

    $city = $faker->city;

    return [
        'city' => $city,
        'value' => strtolower($city)
    ];
});
```